# Object oriented programming, add_action in constructor not firing

Tags: hooks, actions, oop

I am trying to write a class that adds an action to the save_post hook, but the post_updated function never gets called. I tried some variations, but it never gets called. Am I doing something wrong?

```
class automatic_forwarder {
 function __construct() {
     add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'post_updated' ) );
 }

 function post_updated() {
     echo "Working";
 }
}
```

Then in the index.php file of the plugin I am writing the following code:

```
require_once('inc/automatic_forwarder.php');

$mypluginclass = new automatic_forwarder();
```

Comment: Are you instantiating `automatic_forwarder`? i.e. `new automatic_forwarder;`

Comment: I have added the initiation code.

Comment: At what point are you loading/instantiating the class? In your theme's `functions.php`? In your main plugin file? In a function attached to another hook?

Comment: In the index.php of the current plugin.

Comment: Are you sure it never gets called? Your echo is probably working but never seen. Try `wp_die( 'Working' );` instead.

Comment: Even if I add die, the loading still works... but if I add `echo "test";' I see that... I am really clueless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21543/discussion-between-mebu83-and-thedeadmedic).